# "Weird" value in my database

Tags: mysql

I sometimes see values in (MySQL) databases of which I don't understand the meaning of. Here is one example:

```
a:26:{i:0;s:2:"22";i:1;s:2:"24";i:2;s:1:"2";i:3;s:2:"26";i:4;s:1:"1";i:5;s:2:"18";i:6;s:2:"17";i:7;s:1:"8";i:8;s:1:"5";i:9;s:2:"12";i:10;s:2:"19";i:11;s:2:"10";i:12;s:2:"15";i:13;s:2:"20";i:14;s:2:"13";i:15;s:2:"21";i:16;s:1:"7";i:17;s:2:"25";i:18;s:1:"3";i:19;s:1:"4";i:20;s:2:"14";i:21;s:2:"23";i:22;s:2:"27";i:23;s:1:"9";i:24;s:1:"6";i:25;s:2:"11";}
```

What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is data created by php `serialize` and decoded by php `unserialize`.
It translates to the following array:

```
array (
  0 => '22',
  1 => '24',
  2 => '2',
  3 => '26',
  4 => '1',
  5 => '18',
  6 => '17',
  7 => '8',
  8 => '5',
  9 => '12',
  10 => '19',
  11 => '10',
  12 => '15',
  13 => '20',
  14 => '13',
  15 => '21',
  16 => '7',
  17 => '25',
  18 => '3',
  19 => '4',
  20 => '14',
  21 => '23',
  22 => '27',
  23 => '9',
  24 => '6',
  25 => '11',
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Good to know!